# Mortgage Calc outputs -e value

Tags: c++, math, equation

I have compiled and run the my equation and it seems to work completely fine from a an user interface and from the compile side, but the equation is getting lost in the inheritance somewhere.  Any thoughts?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;
class MortgageCalc
{
    private:
        float loan, interest, term;
        int years;
        float monthlyDue, totalDue, totalInt;
    public:
        MortgageCalc() = default;
        void setData(float, float, float);
        float setLoan(void);  //mutator
        float setIntrest(void);     //mutator
        float setYears(void);
        float setTerm ();   //mutator
        float getMonthlyDue();
        float getTotalDue();
        float getTotalInt();
};

void MortgageCalc::setData(float l, float i, float y)
{
   loan = l;
   interest = i;
   years = y;
}

float MortgageCalc::setLoan(void)
{
   return loan;
}

float MortgageCalc::setIntrest(void)
{
    return interest;
}

float MortgageCalc::setYears(void)
{
   return years;
}

float MortgageCalc::setTerm()
{
     term = pow((1 + ((interest/100) / 12)), (12 * years));  //simple interest calculation with power calc to establish whole number translation
     return term;
}

float MortgageCalc::getMonthlyDue()
{
    monthlyDue = (loan * ((interest/100) / 12) * term) / (term - 1);
    return monthlyDue;
}

float MortgageCalc::getTotalDue()
{
    totalDue = (getMonthlyDue() * (years * 12));
    return totalDue;
}

float MortgageCalc::getTotalInt()
{
    totalInt = (getTotalDue() - loan);
    return totalInt;
}

int main()
{
    MortgageCalc mort1;
    int choice = 0;
    int years = 0;
    double term(0) , loan(0), interest(0);

    cout << "Enter the total loan amount on your mortgage loan: $";  //established loan variable
        cin >> loan;

    cout << "Enter the interest rate (in whole #'s only): ";  //establishes interest rate variable
        cin >> interest;

    cout << "Enter the length of the loan in years: "; //establishes term of payments
        cin >> years;

    mort1.setData(loan, interest, years);

    while (choice != 3)   //loop for menu options and clean function exit
    {
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Program to Calculate Mortgage Payments" << endl <<
                "1. Monthly Payment" << endl <<
                "2. Total Payment" << endl <<
                "3. Exit" << endl << endl <<
                "Enter an option above: ";
        cin >> choice;

        if (choice == 1)
            cout << "Monthly payment due is " << mort1.getMonthlyDue() << "." << endl;
        else if (choice == 2)
            cout << "Total amount for entire loan payments plus interest is $" << mort1.getTotalDue() << "." << endl <<
                    "Total Interest Paid for this loan amount  $" << mort1.getTotalInt() << "." << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the text output:

```
Enter the total Loan Amount: $100,000 
Enter the interest Rate: 5 
Enter the length of the loan: 10 
Program to calculate mort payments 
1. Monthly Payments 
2. Total Payments 
3. Exit Enter and Option Above: 1 
Monthly Payment Due is: -1.56868e-036
```

Comment: What's your input, expected output, and the observed output?

Comment: @RSahu when I input 100000, 5, 10..... It should output monthly payment $1060.66 Total Payment with interest $127279.00

Comment: Please add the text (not a screen capture or picture) of your output to the question.

Comment: Although you do not use these several of your setters are declared and implemented wrongly: I mean `setYears()` should take an argument and set the years not return the # of years.

Comment: @drescherjm I'm sorry but I am still a newbie at this, what do you mean they are implemented wrong?

Comment: In this case your `setYears()` is really the same as a getter. Although (the wrong implementation of your setters) this has nothing to do with a wrong calculation since these are not used.

Comment: @drescherjm   Thanks, was hoping it had something to do with the calculation though.  Any thoughts?

Comment: You still have not posted the text output from your program to the question. This is a requirement. Eventually the question will likely be closed because of that.

Comment: Here is the text output:
Enter the total Loan Amount: $100,000
Enter the interest Rate: 5
Enter the length of the loan: 10

Program to calculate mort payments
1. Monthly Payments
2. Total Payments
3. Exit 

Enter and Option Above: 1
Monthly Payment Due is: -1.56868e-036

Comment: Please let me know if that is correct for posting the text output.

Comment: `term` is not set when `mort1.getMonthlyDue()` is executed causing the calculation to return random data.

Comment: Maybe you wanted to call `setTerm()` after you set the years in `setData()`

Comment: I found that in the first minute of debugging using Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: @drescherjm  BRILLIANT!  Thanks mate...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the support on this one, I found out that the term call was being placed outside of the child reference and therefore was able to update the field and return the correct input.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;
class MortgageCalc
{
    private:
        float loan, interest, term;
        int years;
        float monthlyDue, totalDue, totalInt;
    public:
        MortgageCalc() = default;
        void setData(float, float, float);
        float setLoan(void);  //mutator
        float setIntrest(void);     //mutator
        float setYears(void);
        float setTerm ();   //mutator
        float getMonthlyDue();
        float getTotalDue();
        float getTotalInt();
};

void MortgageCalc::setData(float l, float i, float y)
{  //copies arguments from input to private members
   loan = l;
   interest = i;
   years = y;
   setTerm();
}

float MortgageCalc::setTerm()
{  //simple interest calculation with power calc to establish whole number translation
     term = pow((1 + ((interest/100) / 12)), (12 * years));
     return term;
}

float MortgageCalc::setLoan(void)
{  //returns loan amt to private member
   return loan;
}

float MortgageCalc::setIntrest(void)
{  //returns interest amt to private member
    return interest;
}

float MortgageCalc::setYears(void)
{  //returns years to private member
   return years;
}



float MortgageCalc::getMonthlyDue()
{  //simple cal to output monthly
    monthlyDue = (loan * ((interest/100) / 12) * term) / (term - 1);
    return monthlyDue;
}

float MortgageCalc::getTotalDue()
{
    totalDue = (getMonthlyDue() * (years * 12));
    return totalDue;
}

float MortgageCalc::getTotalInt()
{
    totalInt = (getTotalDue() - loan);
    return totalInt;
}

int main()
{
    MortgageCalc mort1;
    int choice = 0;
    int years = 0;
    double term(0) , loan(0), interest(0);

    cout << "Enter the total loan amount on your mortgage loan: $";  //established loan variable
        cin >> loan;

    cout << "Enter the interest rate (in whole #'s only): ";  //establishes interest rate variable
        cin >> interest;

    cout << "Enter the length of the loan in years: "; //establishes term of payments
        cin >> years;

    mort1.setData(loan, interest, years);

    while (choice != 3)   //loop for menu options and clean function exit
    {
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Program to Calculate Mortgage Payments" << endl <<
                "1. Monthly Payment" << endl <<
                "2. Total Payment" << endl <<
                "3. Exit" << endl << endl <<
                "Enter an option above: ";
        cin >> choice;

        if (choice == 1)
            cout << "Monthly payment due is " << mort1.getMonthlyDue() << "." << endl;
        else if (choice == 2)
            cout << "Total amount for entire loan payments plus interest is $" << mort1.getTotalDue() << "." << endl <<
                    "Total Interest Paid for this loan amount  $" << mort1.getTotalInt() << "." << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```